# Calling a view and generating a PDF in TCPDF at the same time in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, tcpdf

I'm trying to call a controller/method which returns a view,
but also in the same controller I'm creating a PDF,

The problem is, the Buffer of TCPDF object and the view, are messing up,
I had tried with ob_clean and related commands, but still no success, if I return the view, the pdf doesn't show any data, but if I return the pdf with success, the view doesn't show up.

How can I solve this?
example

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->view("some_view"); //Doesn't matter
    $this->createPDF(); //In which order I place them, the result is the same
}

public function createPDF(){
 // settings
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    ob_clean();
    $pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/pdf/file.pdf', 'F');      
}
```

Comment: I tried same thing at my end, but no issues. I didn't use ```ob_start() ob_clean()``` at all. What is mean by gone..? Is there any error?

Comment: which CI version are you using? which TCPDF version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public function createPDF(){
 // settings
    ob_start();
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    ob_end_clean();
    $pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/pdf/file.pdf', 'F');      

}
```

This is working fine for me

> Suggestion try `mpdf`  that simplest pdf generator for CI

link https://github.com/phpclicks/mpdf